# DNS issue on localhost

Tags: visual-studio, dns

I'm trying to run an MVC project in Visual Studio 2013 locally using iis express as the project option.

This refuses to start in Chrome and IE, but will work with Firefox. I am in a corporate environment and cannot access my internet settings for IE (which are also used by Chrome).

Browsing to `http://localhost:50418/home` in IE just times out, except for sometimes where it redirects to a completely different web application on another ip address.

I have tried replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 and also with my computer name, but neither of those options has worked.

Any ideas of things I could check?

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy configurations in IE, Chrome uses it. Add localhost as exception to make sure this connection won't go to your corporate proxy.

Comment: I can't see the proxy settings unfortunately, they are locked down. I can edit the registry though, I can see in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mirosoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings I have ProxyOverride set to "<-loopback->;tfs:8080"

Comment: Ask your administrator to check this out and add "localhost" and "127.0.0.0/8" as exception in proxy, it's a good practice to avoid this issue.